# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`main_table`.`period`)

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

HELP: I have no idea what is wrong. When i am trying to login to the admin panel of the website, front end is fine. but that shows this error message
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`main_table`.`period`)`

Answer (score 0):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host try once this sql command...

Run this Sql

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default'; UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN'; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Now admin can able to login.